# How to create paginated posts in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, pagination

Can any one tell me how i can split a wordpress post in multiple pages?
This is an example http://www.therichest.com/rich-list/most-popular/top-40-clearest-waters-from-around-the-world/2/

I don't use `<!--nextpage -->` or `<!--more-->`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the pagination plugins available in WordPress directory to achieve this.

With the Advanced Post Pagination plugin you will be able to create pagination very similar to the one in the link you shared.

Once you install the plugin, you can include the content for every new page inside

`[nextpage] [/nextpage]`

You can read up more about it here http://codezag.com/how-to-create-pages-within-wordpress-post/